# External resources in phonegap app after build

Tags: android, image, cordova, external

This is my first post on SOF. OK, let's get to the merits...

Im quite new in Phonegap and mobile applications world but i have some expirience with developing in PHP, C#, JS... but in Phonegap iam stuck in early stage.

I download Phonegap app for windows to testing apps, this software create for me fresh project.

Now i add to index html: `<img src="http://domain.com/img.png" />`.

In desktop phonegap image is visible but after build i see crash link to image icon. I tested this on Andy emulator and on my HTC ONE - the same effect.

I tryed with jquery link, api connection, nodejs+socket.io external resources in my app, in the next step with additional attributs in html markups, in the next step i used many different config.xml combinations (changing/deleting sections with domains ACL).... i have only one configuration file. ( i builded .apk on adobe web page)

...and I still have this problem.

What could be the problem ? What should I check? how should I debug/test ?

thank you in advance and sorry for my English .

Answer (score 0):

try after Addind `<access origin="*" />` in your config.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I had this line in my first approach in config.xml and i check this position witch *, domain.com*, *domain.com*, domain.com/picture.png and with option "subdomains" ... and this is not issue in this case.

thanks!